# How to display an image of expo camera in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I am working on camera in app, where I have took a picture and have convert into base64 now I want to display an image but did not able to display an image . Could someone please help me how to achieve this goal .

Thanks

```
  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
        let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({
            base64: true,
        });
        this.props.cameraToggle(false);
        this.props.image(photo)
        console.log('@@@ take picutre', photo)
    }
}
```

Image Code that I want to render

```
<Image source={{uri:`data:image/png;base64,${cameraImage}`}} style={{width:100,height:100}}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
 let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({
     base64: true,
 });
 this.props.image(photo)
```

The takePictureAsync return an object, so your base64 data is in the field **photo.base64**.

**Solution 2**

You can store the URI into the state without base64.

```
const [photoUri, setPhotoUri] = React.useState(null);
  const cameraRef = React.useRef(null);
  const takePhoto = async () => {
      setPhotoUri(null);
      const camera = cameraRef.current;
      if(!camera) return;
      try {
          const data = await camera.takePictureAsync();
          setPhotoUri(data.uri);
      } catch (error) {
          console.log('error: ', error);
      }
  }
```

Then use it.

```
return (
     <Image source={{uri: photoUri}} />
);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using class-based components. You can render the `image` which is captured from `camera` by setting the response `photo` to a local state and conditionally rendering it.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Image } from "react-native";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";

class Cameras extends React.Component(props) {
  state = {
    captures: "",
  };

  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({
        base64: true,
      });
      this.props.cameraToggle(false);
      this.setState({ captures: photo.uri });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { captures } = this.state;
    return (
      <View flex={1}>
        {this.state.captures ? (
          <Image source={{ uri: captures }} style={{width:50,height:50}} />
        ) : (
          <Camera {...pass in props} />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Cameras;
```

*Note:*
A more clean approach would be to pass the state `captures` as a route param by navigating a different screen and rendering the image on that screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are storing value of photo in `cameraImage`.
I am sharing a working solution with you using expo image picker, give it a try

Your component

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._openCamera}>
    <Text>Open Camera</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

<Image source={this.state.mainImageUrl} />
```

Your function

```
_openCamera = async () => {
    await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    try {
        let result: any = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
            base64: true,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
        });
        if (!result.cancelled) {
            this.setState({
                mainImageUrl: { uri: `data:image/jpg;base64,${result.base64}` }
            });
        }
    } catch (E) {
        console.warn(E);
    }
}
```